# Why the prompt gives me "Access denied"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I execute this C code that uses system() to invoke the dir command but changes all letters written to the screen to lowercase.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTRING 100

int main(void){
    char command[MAXSTRING], *tmp_filename;
    int c;
    FILE *ifp;

    tmp_filename = tmpnam(NULL);
    sprintf(command, "dir > %s", tmp_filename);
    system(command);
    ifp = fopen(tmp_filename, "r");
    while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
        putchar(tolower(c));
    remove(tmp_filename);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to execute the code with linux changing "dir" with "ls" and works 100%. Why with visual studio i obtain an "Access denied"? Thanks.

Comment: Try to run the `.exe` file generated giving Administrator Privileges.

Comment: Probably because you don't have access to something you are trying to access. In my case your code works perfectly. And I was running it without  any administrative rights.

Comment: Running visual studio as admin the code works perfectly!

Comment: @wing  Not really. `tmpnam` guarantees the uniqueness of the name for the current working directory. You are creating the file in the root directory of the drive instead, where its uniqueness is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpnam` in MSVC library generates a name in `\name` format. Which means that if you use that name directly, you will attempt to write something into the root directory of the current drive. Apparently your account has no rights to do that, which is why you get "Access denied" response from `dir`.

`tmpnam` guarantees that the name is unique for the current working directory, which means that it is you who are supposed to ensure that the file is created in the current working directory (not in the root of the drive). You are supposed to either add the full path to the name, or get rid of the `\` in front. I.e. do something along the lines of

```
tmp_filename = tmpnam(NULL);

// Assuming `tmp_filename` is not null
if (*tmp_filename == '\\')
  ++tmp_filename;
```

Comment: @AnT so, if i wanna create the file in the working directory instead in the root, what is supposed to do?
Or, how i can find the path?